# Get length of Bezier curve with python? (For driver)

Tags: python, bezier-curves, drivers

Is there a way to get the length of a Bezier curve in Python such that I can use it in a driver?

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/D1810

Comment: If you know the control points of bezier (which you do with 12 driver variables - 4 points each 3 axis) you can calculate the exact length in a PyDriver like this: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html. However it is much cheaper to segment the curve and approximate with those segment lengths.

Answer (score 1):

The animation node plugin implements a node for calculating the length of a curve:

You find the sources [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/tree/master/nodes/spline).
[image]

An older [BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?206790-Length-of-a-Bezier-curve-in-2-5) also provides some snippets.

Comment: Is there a way to get this into a driver?

Comment: @PGmath With animation nodes you can modify other objects properties. I never tried to use both.

Comment: I am trying to drive a modifier property (array count), can animation nodes do that?

Comment: What you're probably after is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZndDvxL-gQE