# How do I get the length of a curve in blender?

Tags: animation, objects, interface, bezier-curves

So I want to move an object along a curve exactly once.  In order to do that I am using the curve modifier along the x-axis and I am going to animate the object.   Is there any way to find the length of the curve(how much I need to move the object) so that the animation will be seamless?

Comment: Curve modifier is generally used for deformation purposes, not animation. If you want to move an object along a curve you should probably use either a Path Constraint or Parent to Follow Path

Comment: It still does the exact same thing

Comment: Still the same as???  Can you elaborate on your animation with a diagram or sample file? Calculating the curve length has been covered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47926/get-length-of-bezier-curve-with-python-for-driver)  Another way to estimate curve length  is to use a small single edge mesh with arrray mod set to fit curve, and look at the object dimensions.  @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  [Old but good example of using curve modifier to drive a car rig along curve Roubal 2009](http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorials/Cars_Animation_Tutorial.pdf)